# How to get full hierarchical name of property within a for loop

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, modelstate

I have some complex validation happening within an MVC 5 application, where I need to manually add model errors, example below.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Form.Actions.Count; i++)
{
  var identifiedHasValue = Form.Actions[i].Action.IdentificationDate.HasValue;

  if (!identifiedHasValue)
  {
    modelState.AddModelError("Form.Actions[" + i + "].Action.IdentificationDate", "Date identified is required.");
  }                    
}
```

My question is, can I get the full property name to add to the error in the format **Form.Actions[0].Action.IdentificationDate** programmatically?

Comment: I don't think that is possible without using reflection, something I would shy away from if at all possible.

Comment: Yeah it would be happening lots of times in a loop so avoiding reflection. Thanks.